# How can I get the row value when edit any text in row of scrolling table in Gojs?

Tags: javascript, gojs

I'm working with scrolling table in Gojs. 
I've set the property **"editable: true"** for my table. Now, suppose I've edited a text in any column of a row, then how can I get the data for this entire row or edited text?
Please let me know if you know this.

Here is my code:

```
            var nodeJson;
        var $ = go.GraphObject.make;
        var inputFieldTable = [
            { ID: "001", Name: "Input 1", Text: "Err1" },
            { ID: "002", Name: "Input 2", Text: "Err2" },
            { ID: "003", Name: "Input 3", Text: "Err3" },
            { ID: "004", Name: "Input 4", Text: "Err4" }
        ];

        var outputFieldTable = [
            { ID: "101", Name: "Output 1", Text: "Integer" },
            { ID: "102", Name: "Output 2", Text: "Integer" },
            { ID: "103", Name: "Output 3", Text: "Integer" },
            { ID: "104", Name: "Output 4", Text: "String" },
            { ID: "105", Name: "Output 5", Text: "String" },
            { ID: "106", Name: "Output 6", Text: "Double" }
        ];
        myDiagram =
            $(go.Diagram, "myDiagramDiv",
                {
                    initialContentAlignment: go.Spot.Center,
                    "undoManager.isEnabled": true,
                    allowMove: false,
                    allowDelete: true,
                    allowCopy: false,
                    allowDragOut: false,
                    allowDrop: false
                });

        myDiagram.nodeTemplate =
            $(go.Node, "Vertical",
                {
                    selectionObjectName: "SCROLLING",
                    resizable: false, resizeObjectName: "SCROLLING",
                    portSpreading: go.Node.SpreadingNone
                },
                new go.Binding("location").makeTwoWay(),
                $(go.TextBlock,
                    { font: "bold 14px sans-serif" },
                    new go.Binding("text", "key")),
                $(go.Panel, "Auto",
                    $(go.Shape, { fill: "white" }),
                    $("ScrollingTable",
                        { stretch: go.GraphObject.Fill },
                        new go.Binding("TABLE.itemArray", "items"),
                        new go.Binding("TABLE.column", "left", function (left) { return left ? 2 : 0; }),
                        new go.Binding("desiredSize", "size").makeTwoWay(),
                        {
                            name: "SCROLLING",
                            desiredSize: new go.Size(100, 100),
                            "TABLE.itemTemplate":
                            $(go.Panel, "TableRow",
                                {
                                    defaultStretch: go.GraphObject.Horizontal,
                                    fromSpot: go.Spot.LeftRightSides,
                                    toSpot: go.Spot.LeftRightSides,
                                    fromLinkable: true,
                                    toLinkable: true,
                                },
                                new go.Binding("portId", "Name"),
                                $(go.TextBlock, { column: 1 }, new go.Binding("text", "Name")),
                                $(go.TextBlock, { column: 2 }, new go.Binding("text", "Text"), { editable: true })
                            ),
                            "TABLE.defaultColumnSeparatorStroke": "gray",
                            "TABLE.defaultColumnSeparatorStrokeWidth": 0.5,
                            "TABLE.defaultRowSeparatorStroke": "gray",
                            "TABLE.defaultRowSeparatorStrokeWidth": 0.5,
                            "TABLE.defaultSeparatorPadding": new go.Margin(1, 3, 0, 3)
                        }
                    )
                )
            );

        myDiagram.model = $(go.GraphLinksModel,
            {
                linkFromPortIdProperty: "fromPort",
                linkToPortIdProperty: "toPort",
                nodeDataArray: [
                    {
                        key: "Input", left: true, location: new go.Point(0, 0), size: new go.Size(170, 100),
                        items: inputFieldTable
                    },
                    {
                        key: "Output", location: new go.Point(300, 0), size: new go.Size(170, 100),
                        items: outputFieldTable, editable: true
                    }
                ]
            });

        //Function to handle editing of Scrolling Tables row data
        myDiagram.addDiagramListener("TextEdited",
            function (e) {
               // alert("Text is changed.");
                var part = e.subject.part;                  
                if (part.data.key.toUpperCase() == "INPUT") {
                    myDiagram.rollbackTransaction();
                    return false;
                }
                else if (part.data.key.toUpperCase() == "OUTPUT") {
                    if ((part instanceof go.Node)) {
                        //NEED TO KNOW THE ENTIRE ROW DATA HERE
                    }
                }

            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you asking about how to get to the item data from within your "TextEdited" listener?

- `e.subject` will be the edited **TextBlock**.
- `e.subject.panel` will be the containing **Panel**, which is a "TableRow" in your **Panel.itemTemplate**.
- `e.subject.panel.data` will be the item data -- i.e. the data for that row.

This applies to all Panels with itemArrays -- not just in a "ScrollingTable".

It's a little odd for a **TextBlock.editable** TextBlock not to have a TwoWay **Binding**, but it can be OK depending on what you do in your "TextEdited" listener.

Comment: +1 for quick reply @Walter. Actually i wanted to fetch data of a row in which I'm editing the text, so that I can find my unique key value and then perform some operations in NodeDataArray of this table. 
Your answer is sufficient for me to retrieve the row data. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you'll have to get all the values from the model by calling the below

```
myDiagram.model.nodeDataArray
```

you'll then need to iterate through the objects to determine what values have changed.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I knew this. Actually nodeDataArray contains entire data. But i want the data of a particular row in which I'm editing the text.